# Why do I get a reference error even though I defined the function?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following code that would execute, but on a button click that calls function 'Auth', I get an error that it is not defined. Why is that? I did define it in the below code, did I not?

```
app.get('/sign-in', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('sign-in', {
    title: 'Sign In'
  })

  function Auth(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword('email@email.com', 'password').catch(function(error) {
      var errorCode = error.code
      var errorMessage = error.message
      console.log(errorCode)
      console.log(errorMessage)
    })
  }
})
```

It's called here (pug):

```
 h2 Please sign in
 form(class='form-signin' role='form')
 input#email.form-control(type='email' placeholder='E-mail address' required='' autofocus='')
 input#password.form-control(type='password' placeholder='Password' required='')
 button.btn.btn-lg.btn-primary.btn-block(type='submit' onclick='Auth(event)') Sign In
```

**EDITED**:

```
(pug file)

link(rel='script', href='../public/javascripts/scripts.js')
body
.container
h2 Please sign in
form(class='form-signin' role='form')
input#email.form-control(type='email' placeholder='E-mail address' required='' autofocus='')
input#password.form-control(type='password' placeholder='Password' required='')
button.btn.btn-lg.btn-primary.btn-block(type='submit') Sign In


(public/javascripts/scripts.js)

$('button').on('click', function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
url: '/api/sign-in',
method: 'POST',
data: {
email: $('#email').val(),
password: $('#password').val()
}
});
}

(app.js)
function Auth(email, password) {
return firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
}   

app.get('sign-in', function(req,res,next) {
res.render('sign-in', { title: 'Sign In' })
})  

app.get('/api/sign-in', function(req, res, next) {
Auth(req.body.email, req.body.password)
.then(function() {
console.log('success!')
})
.catch(function(error) {
console.log(error)
})
})
```

Comment: what is not defined? the function Auth or something within it?

Comment: Where do you call auth? I formatted the code and do not see it.

Comment: Where is this button defined? Functions are not visible from outside their scope, and you defined this function within the scope of the `app.get` function.

Comment: Not enough code to help.  Where is the script for the buttons click handler?

Comment: Also your function Auth is defined inside app.get not outside of it... so the scope of Auth is local to app.get

Comment: it's not defined, you have defined it inside the scope of an request callback and also call res.render and then defined it. move it to upper scope. Also I might be wrong but you mix client side with server side JavaScript and expect it to work with a button click ?

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: Use the `{}` button  when you post code

Comment: Auth is defined inside the app.get... it is not at a scope where your button will see it

Comment: @kupak12 that's code in your Node server-side stuff? You can't call functions in your Node code directly from browser-side JavaScript or HTML markup.

Comment: I thought since it is in the GET request of 'sign-in', that function would be defined too?

Comment: node.js code is not going to be returned to the browser

Comment: You are trying to use client code inside your server code. That's not how it works.

Comment: No, absolutely not. There's a network protocol between your Node code and your browser code. Your Node code runs on your server, while the browser code runs in people's web browsers.

Comment: Oh ok. Where am I supposed to put it?

Comment: Seems like you would make an endpoint to log in and call that with a form submission or Ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem, the functions you define on your express server won't work on the client, that's now how it works.

- You need to create an Auth function on your express app that will try to login to firebase.
- Create an endpoint that when called/accessed via POST/GET method will run the Auth function.
- Then on the client side, create a function that will do an ajax call to your server (express) endpoint when the button is clicked.

e.g.

express code:

```
app.post('/api/sign-in', function(req, res, next) {
  firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(req.query.username, req.query.password)
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
});
```

client code (using jQuery for clarity):

```
$('#button').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    url: '/api/sign-in',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
      username: $('#user').val(),
      password: $('#pass').val()
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but I got an events.js (throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event). Where is the mistake?

Comment: Could you update your question with your code fixed? Just to see where the error could be.

It seems to me that you are still trying to run client code on the server.

Comment: @kupak12 i've updated the code with small fixes. the error you mention with `events.js` is from the node side, which is hard to debug without a workable example.

Comment: I don't get an error now. However, when I click on the button, nothing gets displayed in the console. Any tips what might be wrong?

Comment: You don't have anything to handle the successful call, i'd recommend to read through the [firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#signInWithEmailAndPassword) on how to handle the `firebase.Promise` it returns.